# Swift: No such file or directory, LocationPicker Module

Tags: swift, xcode, directory, pbxcp

I'm currently working on an iOS app. I'm using Cocoa Pods and after installing the `LocationPicker` pod suddenly I've gotten a specific error of:

> Error: /Users/spare/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/"Title of my app"-aqffstyicckarrblwyjhcqxtbpea/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/LocationPicker/LocationPicker.framework: No such file or directory

I have spent two days trying to solve this, I have tried cleaning the build folder. Reinstalling the module. Updating the swift language. Checked the "Embedded Binaries" and a lot more, I have run out of things to try.

In advance appreciate any help.

Comment: When does this error appear? At build time? Does it crash? Is locationpicker a objective-c library?

Comment: how did you link the framework into your app?  Show us a bit more of your setup.

Comment: This error appears when I try to run this app in xcode, it simply says build failed. It's a module I have downloaded from github, it's in swift and I added it to my Podfile (I'm using Cocoa Pods), and then "import LocationPicker" is all it needs.